# create export button in pentaho

Tags: pentaho, dashboard, dashboard-designer, pentaho-design-studio

I try to create the export button to export dashboard to pdf file in pentaho like this :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1fj69yHiGc

hope you help me, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The general/best way to do this is to actually re-implement the dashboard as a Pentaho report and use CGG to get your charts into the report.

Like this:

http://www.ambientbi.co.uk/?p=357

Is there any reason why you specifically want to use PhantomJS?  The PRD option will give you much better control of the final report, and wont have differences on different browsers, which is surely what you want from a PDF?

Comment: if we use PRD,I think it is not good if the dashboard have many different charts.

Comment: why not? if you use PRD the charts displayed are the same as those in the dashboard so there is no maintenance headache.  Laying out the charts in PRD to match the dashboard is also a piece of cake.  So whats the issue exactly?

Comment: but it's not good for customer use, customer usually wants to use on client browers to export

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, I've never come across that. The dashboard has to be served up from a server, so it makes sense to build the PDF on the server too.  Each to their own though.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did with CTools CGG! I saw http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1fj69yHiGc . Can you or anyone tell me how to do that (use PhantomJS).